# Alternative to GROUP BY MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get the same result as this query without the use of group by.

```
SELECT emp_no,salary, max(to_date) to_date FROM employees.salaries
```

group by emp_no;

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What exactly I you trying to achieve?

Comment: The query doesn't make sense without a group by - emp_no and salary will be indeterminate,

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from employees.salaries s
where s.to_date = (
    select max(s1.to_date) 
    from employees.salaries s1 
    where s1.emp_no = s.emp_no and s1.salary = s.salary
);
```

Or, in MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*, row_number() over(partition by emp_no, salary order by to_date desc) rn
    from employees.salaries s
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp_no, salary, to_date 
FROM employees.salaries t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM employees.salaries t2
                   WHERE t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no
                     AND t1.salary = t2.salary
                     AND t1.to_date < t2.to_date )
```

or

```
SELECT t1.emp_no, t1.salary, t1.to_date 
FROM employees.salaries t1
LEFT JOIN employees.salaries t2 ON t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no
                               AND t1.salary = t2.salary
                               AND t1.to_date < t2.to_date
WHERE t2.to_date IS NULL
```

If there exists the records which are full duplicates by `(emp_no, salary, to_date)` expression then use `SELECT DISTINCT`.